Django- how to convert <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'> to an image?
I have a form that uploads an image to my view; the uploaded image type is:
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>

I want to process the image though; thus I need it in PIL or CV2 format.
How can I do that ?

Django File actually implements all the required methods of a typical file object which PIL.Image.open() needs. An InMemoryUploadedFile is a Django File.
You can reopen the File in the correct mode and then pass it to PIL.Image.open(). This should suffice: [1]
someFile: InMemoryUploadedFile = # •••Already has a value•••
someFile = someFile.open("b+")
with PIL.Image.open(someFile) as img:
    # •••Do something•••

[1] The solution doesn’t copy the underlying bytes of the file object but simply passes a handle of it from one routine to another. BEWARE OF DATA RACES.

Thank you for your answer; it did yield a PIL image but in the case of  needing a "CV2"  image, what may I do ?

PIL to "OpenCV image"

Thank you so much your solution worked perfectly +1.
